# avoid vertical move using carrousel in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using the [react-responsive-carousel](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel) library to have a `carousel`.

everything works fine, the problem occurs when I do a `swipe up` and `swipe down` the `carousel` moves (see the image):

[image]

I only need it to move when I do a `swipe left` or `swipe right`.

How can I avoid the `swipe up` and `swipe down`?

This is my live code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-nova-5hf06u

this is my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Carousel
      showThumbs={false}
      showStatus={false}
      showIndicators={false}
      showArrows={false}
      emulateTouch={true}
      axis="horizontal"
    >
      <div>
        <img src="https://im.indiatimes.in/content/2017/Nov/in6_1509613195.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://im.indiatimes.in/content/2017/Nov/in6_1509613195.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://im.indiatimes.in/content/2017/Nov/in6_1509613195.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://im.indiatimes.in/content/2017/Nov/in6_1509613195.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://im.indiatimes.in/content/2017/Nov/in6_1509613195.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://im.indiatimes.in/content/2017/Nov/in6_1509613195.jpg" />
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preventMovementUntilSwipeScrollTolerance` prop with `swipeScrollTolerance={100}`.

Comment: What if we need to make it scroll down while swiping upwards? Just like a normal section moves in mobile-screen while swiping vertically.